# How can I use react-quill to provide a user to create a template that can also be previewed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor

I'm looking at an npm library called [react-quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill) but unsure how to achieve the same functionality over at [HTML Code editor with preview](https://htmlcodeeditor.com/)

I need to be able to allow the user enter HTML code that then renders this code within a preview window.

I am new to react-quill and not sure how to achieve this as I would like to provide the user with a toolbar of HTML code options like `h1`, `h2`, `span` etc.

I have tried this code over in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-butterfly-zwq4vk?file=/src/App.js) but it is appearing as a rich text editor with no preview window. I actually want it to appear as a HTML Editor with rendered preview.

I'm also not sure if react-quill can achieve this or if I should be looking at another library?

Just to ensure, what I am actually after is this, but the opposite, that is, allow the user to enter/edit HTML (right screen) and display the output from this (left screen):

https://zenoamaro.github.io/react-quill/

Answer (score 0):

https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/

You need to add toolbar options

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
const toolbarOptions = [
  ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"], // toggled buttons
  ["blockquote", "code-block"],

  [{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }], // custom button values
  [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
  [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }], // superscript/subscript
  [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }], // outdent/indent
  [{ direction: "rtl" }], // text direction

  [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }], // custom dropdown
  [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

  [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }], // dropdown with defaults from theme
  [{ font: [] }],
  [{ align: [] }],

  ["clean"] // remove formatting button
];

function HtmlEditor() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  function handleChange(value) {
    setContent(value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HTML Editor</h1>
      <div className="editor-container">
        <ReactQuill
          value={content}
          onChange={handleChange}
          modules={{ toolbar: toolbarOptions }}
        />
        <div
          className="preview-container"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HtmlEditor;
```

Comment: I tried your code solution above but it doesn't seem to allow the user to initially enter HTML code and the toolbar doesn't show any HTML options for the user to select. I actually need the editor to be HTML and the preview to display the rendered HTML code.